# Return a set of documents with all sub-arrays containing a given value in loopback or nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

How do I return a set of documents that has sub-arrays that matches common values.  To better explain, consider the following data:

```
[
{
    Category: 1,
    Products: [
                {
                    Name: 'ABC',
                    ColorCode:[1,2,3,4,5]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'DEF',
                    ColorCode:[1,2,3,4,5,6]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'GHI',
                    ColorCode:[1,2,3,4,6,7]
                }                   
            ]
},
{
    Category: 2,
    Products: [
                {
                    Name: 'JKL',
                    ColorCode:[4,6,7,]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'MNO',
                    ColorCode:[4,5,6,9,]
                }                   
            ]
},
{
    Category: 3,
    Products: [
                {
                    Name: 'OPQ',
                    ColorCode:[3,4,5,6,9,10]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'RST',
                    ColorCode:[2,3,5,6,9,10]
                }                   
            ]
}]
```

The task is, 
Get all the Categories with all the products containing a specific color code:

For example,
For ColorCode = 6, 
Result should be:

```
[
{
    Category: 2,
    Products: [
                {
                    Name: 'JKL',
                    ColorCode:[4,6,7,]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'MNO',
                    ColorCode:[5,6,9,]
                }                   
            ]
},
{
    Category: 3,
    Products: [
                {
                    Name: 'OPQ',
                    ColorCode:[3,4,5,6,9,10]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'RST',
                    ColorCode:[2,3,5,6,9,10]
                }                   
            ]
}]
```

For ColorCode = 4, 
Result should be:

```
[
{
    Category: 1,
    Products: [
                {
                    Name: 'ABC',
                    ColorCode:[1,2,3,4,5]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'DEF',
                    ColorCode:[1,2,3,4,5,6]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'GHI',
                    ColorCode:[1,2,3,4,6,7]
                }                   
            ]
},
{
    Category: 2,
    Products: [
                {
                    Name: 'JKL',
                    ColorCode:[4,6,7,]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'MNO',
                    ColorCode:[4,5,6,9,]
                }                   
            ]
}]
```

For ColorCode = 7, 
Result should be an empty array:
[]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm still looking and can't find answers... has anyone actually done something similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
// filter out categories that don't contain color code 4
categories.filter(function(category) {
  return category.products.filter(containsColor(4)) > 0;
});

function containsColor(colorCode) {
  return function(product) {
    return product.ColorCode.indexOf(colorCode) >= 0;
  };
}
```